# How does printf free its buffer?

Tags: c, memory, printf

I noticed something odd with valgrind and my system's implementation of printf: when calling printf the first time it allocates 1024 bytes, so I think that it's printf's static internal buffer, but the thing that I noticed is that no matter how you exit the program the memory gets freed, even with `abort`, so my question is how do they do that? Are there threads involved, or signal handlers?

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 42;

    printf("a:%d\nb:%d\n", a, b);
    return (0);
}
```

```c
==419254==
==419254== HEAP SUMMARY:
==419254==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==419254==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==419254==
==419254== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==419254==
==419254== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==419254== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 42;

    printf("a:%d\nb:%d\n", a, b);
    printf("a:%d\nb:%d\n", a, b);
    printf("a:%d\nb:%d\n", a, b);
    printf("a:%d\nb:%d\n", a, b);
    printf("a:%d\nb:%d\n", a, b);
    return (0);
}
```

```c
Same output
```

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 42;

    printf("a:%d\nb:%d\n", a, b);
    abort();
    return (0);
}
```

```c
==423023==
==423023== Process terminating with default action of signal 6 (SIGABRT)
==423023==    at 0x48A418B: raise (raise.c:51)
==423023==    by 0x4883858: abort (abort.c:79)
==423023==    by 0x1091A7: main (in /home/leo/Documents/42_cursus/libs/libft42/a.out)
==423023==
==423023== HEAP SUMMARY:
==423023==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==423023==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==423023==
==423023== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==423023==
==423023== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==423023== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
[1]    423023 abort (core dumped)  valgrind ./a.out
```

Comment: The memory is probably freed before `printf` returns.

Comment: there's nothing to indicate that the buffer is allocated by `printf`, or that it's not freed before it exits. Also `abort()` is not prohibited from doing internal cleanup.

Comment: File streams are closed as the program exits.  Closing a stream releases any memory associated with the file stream (which is `stdout`, of course).  I'm a bit surprised that it is freed when the program is aborted, but the system library can do things a user cannot.  See also the standard C [`atexit()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atexit.html) function.

Comment: I would not expect `printf` to allocate static internal buffer at all. It has no need for it.

Comment: It is implementation dependent.  Fayeure, what compiler (version)/library are you using?

Comment: Does valgrind know about `printf` and/or standard or system library functions and exclude their allocations from consideration of leaks?

Comment: @dbush: no, the memory is allocated, possibly as a side effect of `printf`, for the `stdout` buffer, which is line-buffered or fully buffered by default. `printf` may allocate memory for its own sake and free it, but given only 1 allocation took place, it is more likely the stream buffer. This is all implementation defined anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The memory is allocated as part of the `FILE` object, which is opened for `stdout` either prior to `main` being called or the first time `stdout` is used (depending on implementation).  This memory will be freed when the `FILE` object is closed, which generally happens with `atexit` when the program exits.

Comment: When the program aborts it has no chance to run exit handlers.

Comment: What `abort()` does regarding open streams is implementation defined: *C19 **7.22.4.1 The `abort` function** [...] The `abort` function causes abnormal program termination to occur, unless the signal `SIGABRT` is being caught and the signal handler does not return. Whether open streams with unwritten buffered data are flushed, open streams are closed, or temporary files are removed is implementation-defined. An implementation-defined form of the status unsuccessful termination is returned to the host environment by means of the function call `raise(SIGABRT)`.*

Answer (score 0):

`valgrind` alters process startup and shutdown. In particular, it calls `__libc_freeres` on behalf of the traced process, which does not happen in normal execution. This function is provided specifically for allocation trackers. Consequently, on abnormal termination the buffers are freed *only* when the program is traced by `valgrind` or other such tool.

For more information, see [this glibc bug report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26022) and [this one](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=421931).